# How to automount lvm on startup ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, lvm

**I'll start some background that can be skipped:**
I have an ubuntu machine that I installed some time ago with the default partitioning on a an 80GB hard drive. The machine runs has rTorrent that starts downloading torrents in a folder that gets updated from Dropbox. During the downloads, the files are in a folder called `Downlods`. When the downloads are complete, they are moved to `Public`. Both folders are shared on my home network (open folders shared with windows). I just got my hands on two new (well, you know, newish. They are 80GB each) hard drives and I wanted to give `Downloads` and `Public` some more space.
I did my research, and concluded that lvm is the way to go. I followed a howto and was able to mount my new lv (called lvDownloads) to my `Public` folder and share it. After reboot, the lv didn't mount and it does not mount manually (`sudo mount /dev/sysvg/lvdownloads /home/usr/Public`).

Is lvm my best course of action? Can it be shared and automounted? Should I try an move my current install to lvm too?
**Skip until here**

I created an lv partition on an ubuntu 12.04 server system. `sudo mount /dev/sysvg/lvdownloads /home/usr/Public` does not seem to work after restart. I get:

```
mount: special device /dev/sysvg/lvdownloads does not exist
```

And yet:

```
usr1@linux:~$ sudo vgdisplay
  Couldn't find device with uuid ybwxlu-gy2j-8nbG-tCvu-0gB3-fo8B-O1iSWA.
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               sysvg
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  9
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                2
  Open LV               0
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                2
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               148.05 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              37902
  Alloc PE / Size       30757 / 120.14 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       7145 / 27.91 GiB
  VG UUID               aFe7VF-eAy5-U3AU-L7Ev-iRnl-QrYL-CfNUMD

usr1@linux:~$ sudo lvdisplay
  Couldn't find device with uuid ybwxlu-gy2j-8nbG-tCvu-0gB3-fo8B-O1iSWA.
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                /dev/sysvg/lvdownloads
  VG Name                sysvg
  LV UUID                obUFeB-KR6k-fLuv-gutT-3wxU-zkZU-e2RQYV
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Status              NOT available
  LV Size                148.00 MiB
  Current LE             37
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                /dev/sysvg/downloads
  VG Name                sysvg
  LV UUID                kNpWh4-gY0P-0gTv-vijQ-DD02-rKuu-ntkuh8
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Status              NOT available
  LV Size                120.00 GiB
  Current LE             30720
  Segments               2
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
```

How do I auto automount it on startup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your LVs are not available because the Physical Volume they reside on cannot be find. Check that all your disks are being detected.